# Responsive navigation menubar isn't working on major browsers like Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, menubar

Have a good day ☺️

I coded responsive navigation menubar for mobile phones but on some major browsers like Google Chrome and bing isn't working.

There's showing as desktop view.

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
  menu.classList.toggle("open");
}

// Close the menu when a menu item is clicked (optional)
var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".menu li a");
for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
  menuItems[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    menu.classList.remove("open");
  });
}
```

```css
/* Responsive navigation styles */

nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.menu-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Media queries */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }

  #menu.open {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  #menu.open li {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">Maxin Solutions</div>
    <div class="menu-toggle" onclick="toggleMenu()">&#9776;</div>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu">
        <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

What I can do to resolve this issue?

I tried changing the media screen pixel but still that wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Initially hide your toggle button and show it only on the mobile view.

**Fix**

```css
.menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
  menu.classList.toggle("open");
}

// Close the menu when a menu item is clicked (optional)
var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".menu li a");
for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
  menuItems[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    menu.classList.remove("open");
  });
}
```

```css
/* Responsive navigation styles */

nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.menu-toggle {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Media queries */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }

  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
  }

  #menu.open {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  #menu.open li {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">Maxin Solutions</div>
    <div class="menu-toggle" onclick="toggleMenu()">&#9776;</div>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu">
        <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```